# Acumatica Custom Selector SQL Error - Incorrect Syntax near the keyword

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create a custom Parts selector to search all records if there is no vendor selected, if a vendor is selected I want to filter the selector's results to only include Parts with the vendor selected.

Using PXCustomSelectorAttribute:

SQL Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'
           Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'

```
       [PXNonInstantiatedExtension]
public class SO_SOLine_ExistingColumn : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine>
{
    #region InventoryID  

    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Replace)] //was append
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Part #")]
    [PartSelector(typeof(SOLineExt.usrCusVendor))]
    public int? InventoryID { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class PartSelector : PXCustomSelectorAttribute
{

    [Serializable]
    [PXProjection(typeof(
         Select2<atcVendorItem,
             LeftJoin<InventoryItem,
                   On<InventoryItem.inventoryCD, Equal<atcVendorItem.inventoryCD>, And<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<atcVendorItem.inventoryID>>>>>), Persistent = false)]
    public class atcPartView : IBqlTable
    {
        // DAC W/Inventory Item Table mapped and joined with Vendor Items
    }


    //Selected table
    private Type _MfgField;


    ////way to have multiple description fields 
    public PartSelector(Type MfgField) : base(typeof(atcPartView.inventoryID))
    {
        _MfgField = MfgField;

    }

    protected virtual IEnumerable GetRecords()
    {
        var cache = this._Graph.Caches[BqlCommand.GetItemType(_MfgField)];
        var cbs = (BAccount)cache.Current;

        // make mfgfield 
        if (cbs != null)
        {
            foreach (atcPartView p in PXSelect<atcPartView, Where<atcPartView.vendorID, Equal<Required<SOLineExt.usrMfg>>>>.Select(_Graph, cbs.BAccountID))
            {
                yield return p;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            foreach (atcPartView p in PXSelect<atcPartView, Where<atcPartView.vendorID, IsNotNull>>.Select(_Graph))
            {
                yield return p;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: According to the stack trace, an exception is thrown on line 1693 of your SOOrderEntry extension class. I would suggest using SQL Profiler to capture SQL query causing this error before you make any assumptions of what exactly is causing this issue.

Comment: Thanks Ruslan, does the GetRecords() align with the PXCustomSelectorAttribute class correctly? If I comment the custom selector out of the SOLine Extension this error disappears

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find another exception while debugging in visual studio, 
my issue was because I was trying to cast the field as BAccount when referencing the SOLine Extension. Changing the cast fixed my issue